# Adding scripting functionality to existing C# project

Tags: c#, scripting

I work in a research group and I've been tasked with adding in scripting functionality to a data acquisition program. Ideally, I want to have the ability to write scripts while the data acquisition software is running (and save those scripts as files on the go). A command line might also be nice.

I'm not very experienced at all with C#, but I do have quite a bit of coding experience in other language (Objective-C, Python). I saw this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/12/01/adding-c-scripting-to-your-development-arsenal-part-1/ which details the "Roselyn Scripting Package" but I'm not sure if that's my best option.

Can anybody suggest the easiest way of getting full scripting functionality? (I'm trying to avoid losing months of my life here =p). Links to start at/advice is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You posted an interesting link for me because I just prototyped something like that some weeks ago, but have not implemented yet. My goal is to create a C# "immediate" console on a webpage.

Have some minor issues regarding loading some assemblies programatically and have to reference them explicitly.

Here is the code behind, please later post your solution, I would be interested to know.

This alows to write c# code at runtime and also get a String return.

```
protected void getImmediateResult_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //building the code
        string source = @"using System; 
        class MyType{
        public static String Evaluate(){
        <!expression!>
        }}";

        string expression = this.txtimmediate.Text;
        string finalSource = source.Replace("<!expression!>", expression);
        textcodeCheck.Text = finalSource;
        var compileUnit = new CodeSnippetCompileUnit(finalSource);

        //preparing compilation
        CodeDomProvider provider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider();

        // Create the optional compiler parameters

        //this correctly references the application but no System.Web etc
        string[] refArray = new string[2];

        UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
        refArray[0] = uri.Path;

        //this works
        refArray[1] = "System.Web" + ".dll";

        ////NOT WORKING for non microsoft assemblies
        //var allRefs = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies();
        //string[] refArray = new string[allRefs.Length + 1];
        //int i = 1;
        //foreach (AssemblyName refer in allRefs)
        //{
        //    refArray[i] = refer.Name + ".dll";
        //    i++;
        //}

        var compilerParameters = new CompilerParameters(refArray);

        CompilerResults compilerResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(compilerParameters, compileUnit);
        if (compilerResults.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            //1st error
            this.txtResult.Text = compilerResults.Errors[0].ErrorText;
            return;
        }

        //running it
        Type type = compilerResults.CompiledAssembly.GetType("MyType");
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Evaluate");
        String result = (String)method.Invoke(null, null);


        this.txtResult.Text = result;
    }
```

Comment: If you're using `CodeDom` (`CodeSnippetCompileUnit`, `CSharpCodeProvider`, etc), you don't need that hackish string source, you can build the boilerplate via code.

Comment: @Kroltan Are you sure? I just don't want to type class syntax everytime.

Comment: I mean, the boilerplate can be constructed in code, instead of parsed from a string and replaced. This way you get errors reported more reliably on the snippet rather than the surrounding boilerplate. Example (using C#6, but easily translatable to other versions): http://pastebin.com/5w86FrVb

Comment: Good link and such approach would be the clean one. The hackish approach looks simpler to understand for any dev at first glace tough...

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use IronPython, you can execute scripts directly in C#:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

private static void doPython()
{
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"test.py");
}
```

[Get IronPython here.](http://ironpython.net/)